# Programmatically confirm whether data on my Mac is synced to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, command-line, data-synchronization

I'm writing a script to highlight things I need to resolve before I'm ready to wipe a macOS system.

I use them sans-network often, so it'd be nice to confirm I don't have unsynced apps or classes of data.

Looking for any filesystem locations or commands through which information about app/data sync state is accessible.